# Select objects from a list using LINQ based on a property

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have list of `Beam` objects. How can I `Select` the ones with maximum `Depth` property into another list using LINQ?

```
public class Beam
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Depth { get; set; }
}

var beam1 = new Beam() {Width = 40, Depth = 50};
var beam2 = new Beam() {Width = 40, Depth = 40};
var beam3 = new Beam() {Width = 30, Depth = 50};

var Beams = new List<Beam> {beam1, beam2, beam3};
```

I want to have:

```
SelectedList = {beam1, beam3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` + `OrderByDescending`:

```
List<Beam> maxDepthGroupList = Beams 
    .GroupBy(b => b.Depth)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .First()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, All the answers are correct. The above answer suits what I need better.

Answer (score 4):

Use combination of `Max` and `Where`:

```
var result = Beams.Where(b => b.Depth == Beams.Max(x => x.Depth));
```

but for sure it should be optimized by splitting it into two lines so `Max` won't be called again and again:

```
var max = Beams.Max(x => x.Depth);
var result = Beams.Where(b => b.Depth == max);
```

Comment: That works; but for larger collections I recommend extracting the `Beams.Max(x => x.Depth)` call into a variable outside the `Where` call so `Max` will only be called once.

Comment: He wants a **list** of the max-depth-value items. This is also very inefficient since you calculate the max in every item again. Note that this is LINQ-To-Objects where it won't be optimzed as in LINQ-To-SQL or LINQ-To-Entities. So for every item all items are enumerated to find the max value.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - of course, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Beams = new List<Beam> {beam1, beam2, beam3};

var selected = Beams.GroupBy(b => b.Depth).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).First();
```

**Edit:**
First you group your result by the Depth property. Each group can contain one or more results.
Then you order the groups by the key(Depth in this case) descending.
And then, you take the first element which will be the group with the max depth.

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxDepth = Beams.Max( b => b.Depth );
List<Beam> SelectedList = Beams.Where( b => b.Depth == maxDepth );
```